# dynamodb list tables and their provisioned throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to list all the tables in dynamodb and their max read and write capacity either using the AWS CLI or boto or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

You want `describe-table`. To get a list of tables and indexes with their capacities, you could do something like this: (in bash)

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --query TableNames --output text | \
  xargs -n 1 aws dynamodb describe-table \
  --query 'Table.{name: TableName, capacity: ProvisionedThroughput}' \
  --table-name
```

yields:

```
{
  "name": "table-name",
  "capacity": {
    "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 20,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 20
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this command will help 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html

Answer (score 0):

I can get list of the tables with this crude script but it doesn't list capacities

aws --region us-east-1 dynamodb list-tables | sed -e 's|[[{}]||g' | sed -e 's|]||g' | egrep -v 'TableName' | sed -e 's|[\",]||g'